# Webdriver-manager ModuleNotFoundError: "Packaging"

Tags: python

I'm on Windows 11, using Python Python 3.10.8 and pip 22.3.

I'm trying to create a new selenium project using webdriver-manager for the webdriver.

When I create a new project, I pip install webdriver-manager.

I have tried in venvs, as well as resinstalling python but get the same result.

Then I try to import webdriver-manager and it fails.

```
from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
```

I get the error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'packaging'
```

Full stack trace:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "z:\Social Research\TikTok\selenium\learning\whyWontUInstall\main.py", line 1, in <module>
    from webdriver_manager.chrome import ChromeDriverManager
  File "C:\Users\noahp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\chrome.py", line 7, in <module>
    from webdriver_manager.drivers.chrome import ChromeDriver
  File "C:\Users\noahp\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\site-packages\webdriver_manager\drivers\chrome.py", line 1, in <module>
    from packaging import version
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'packaging'
```

Comment: the pip command is this: `pip install webdriver-manager`.

Comment: I am using `windows 11` with `python v 3.10` and confirm the above works.

Answer (score 10):

It's a [webdriver-manager bug](https://github.com/SergeyPirogov/webdriver_manager/issues/454), fixed in the master.
Install packages like the following.

```
> pip install packaging
```

Answer (score 2):

```
pip install packaging
```

or

```
pip install webdriver-manager==3.8.2
```

newest version of webdriver-manager is 3.8.4 which requires packaging module